# how long does it take to create an Azure Cloud Service? How to view log information?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I'm brand new to Azure. I'm trying to get a Cloud Service running with 3 web roles.

Last night I created the .cspkg and .cscfg files, exported the certificates and uploaded everything to Azure manager. The manager said my Cloud Service was successful, however for the last 10 hours when I click on "Cloud Services" in the manager it shows my service, but it says "Creating" with wait gif under "SERVICE STATUS".

Is it really still creating? Or did it fail? Is it possible to view more detailed information about the creation process and/or any log files?

Thanks,

Comment: I recommend deleting it and creating another one. There must have been a glitch.

Comment: Thanks, took me a while to figure out how, but I was eventually able to delete it using the Azure PowerShell.

Comment: doesn't it allow you to delete a hosted service from management web portal?

Comment: not one that is stuck in "creating", the delete button was disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something "bad" has happened. Service Spin up time should be at most a few minutes. 
I've seen it take up to 10-15 minutes depending on the hosting center and the number of scaled instances that need to come up but 10 hrs something has definitely gone wrong.

I would delete the service and start again. If you experience the same problem, have a look in your service start up code and make sure that there's no exceptions/infinite loops, other problems in there that might be causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Do you know how to delete the cloud service? The delete button is grayed out. And I'm being charged for the could service that is totally stuck and I cannot delete it! I think it is back to AWS for me... I just need to figure out how to stop this thing from killing my credit card.

Comment: you need to stop it first.

Comment: thanks, but it was never running. I could do nothing from the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

It may miss any assembly references. If you included any assembly references(packages that are not part of .net) then please ensure that its **copy to local** attribute is set to **true**.